# converting fgetcsv response into specific json

Tags: php, arrays, json, fgetcsv

I have a .CSV file with headings:

```
Description, BusinessSurname, IsCustomer, IsSupplier, AddressType, Business 
Address, IsInternational.
```

First row:

```
Contact1, Contact1, True, True, Business, 123 Fake St, False
```

Remaining rows not important, its just more like that - examples.  I have a few rows of data in there.

I need to get it into this format json:

```
{
Description:'Desc_47AE3208-87F5-4BBA-BE40-AA4130AB4768',
SurnameBusinessName:'Name_Business',
IsCustomer:true,
IsSupplier:true,
Addresses:
[
{AddressType:'Business',Line1:'addr1_bus',IsInternational:false},
{AddressType:'Postal',Line1:'addr1_pos',IsInternational:true}
]
}
```

I have tried a few different ways, but none of them specifically give me a json like this with the address nested.  I can leave the second address (postal address) out.

If I use this code:

```
        $filename = 'contacts1.csv';
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        $count = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            $count++;
            if ($count == 1){
                continue;
            }
        $json = json_encode($data, true);
        echo $json;
        };
```

I get this for example:

```
["Contact1","Contact1","TRUE","TRUE","Business","123 High Street Sydney NSW 2000","FALSE"]
["Contact2","Contact2","TRUE","TRUE","Business","124 High Street Sydney NSW 2000","FALSE"]
["Contact3","Contact3","TRUE","TRUE","Business","125 High Street Sydney NSW 2000","FALSE"]
```

Is there a way to get the json I need, and if I can't get the required json automatically, is there a way I can extract the values of each row, and assign to a variable, and manually create the required json for each row, using a for loop, while loop, etc?  EG:

```
{
Description: $description,
SurnameBusinessName: $BusinessSurname,
etc...
}
```

Comment: along with csv headers - show csv rows

Comment: I've show example of the csv rows.  thanks.  And you can already see what was in the csv rows by looking at the output i was getting.  same thing basically.

Comment: Answered here already : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781279/how-to-make-fgetcsv-to-be-the-json-i-wantadfasdgfasdf/44781458#44781458

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this, however I had given up on this API endpoint and went to a simpler one without nesting.  Due to the strictness of the json format this API will accept I basically assigned each value from my csv to a variable and manually created the json needed.  Although this code below is for the Accounts endpoint, I can use the exact same method for any endpoint because I am kind of manually creating the json.  And its the only way it can work I think as some fields are strings like AccountName, some integers like AcountType.

```
$file = 'acc.csv';
    $mode = 'r';
    $handle = fopen($file, $mode);
    while(($csv = fgetcsv($handle)) !==FALSE){
        foreach($csv as $row => $value){
            $data = $row.$value;
            switch ($row){
                case '0':
                    $accounttype = $value;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    $accountname = $value;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $hint = $value;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $status = $value;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    $sortorder = $value;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    $accountcode = $value;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    $parentaccountcatid = $value;

                    $json = "
                    {
      AccountType:" . $accounttype . ",
      AccountName:'" . $accountname . "',
      Hint:'" . $hint . "',
      Status:" . $status . ",
      SortOrder:" . $sortorder . ",
      AccountCode:'" . $accountcode . "',
      ParentAccountingCategoryID:'" . $parentaccountcatid . "'
     }"; 
    //echo $json;
```